# Which UK airport uses different approaches for noise reduction?

Tags: airport, approach, noise-reduction

I remember hearing about a British airport that had two approaches that were used on alternating weeks. They implemented this pilot project (no pun intended) so that different houses would be overflown each week, giving residents the impression that noise from the airport was reduced. What airport was this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently it's called Runway Alteration. The only hits I got were referring to [Heathrow airport](http://www.heathrow.com/noise/heathrow-operations/runway-alternation), so my guess is this is the only airport that uses this procedure.

Actually, the alternation is in two ways: per part of the day, and per week.
During week 1, from 06:00 to 15:00 runway 27L is used, and from 15:00 until last departure 27R is used.

The week after this, the things are reversed:
From 06:00 to 15:00 runway 27R is used, and from 15:00 until last departure 27L is used.
So the people living under the approach of 27L will have noise in the first part of the day in week 1, and during the second part of the day in week 2.
See the full programme [here](http://www.heathrow.com/file_source/HeathrowNoise/Static/Runway_Alternation_Programme-2015.pdf).

It is influenced by the six factors below (taken from the same source):

> - Daytime patterns of runway alternation are different to night-time    patterns: at night there are only a handful of landings and very few take-offs.
> - Aircraft land and take off    into the wind, so the [wind direction](http://www.heathrow.com/noise/heathrow-operations/wind-direction) has a big effect on flight patterns.
> - Government policy currently favours aircraft taking off    towards the west. Even when the wind blows from the east, aircraft    could
>     still fly in from east and take off towards the west. This is because we have a [westerly preference](http://www.heathrow.com/noise/heathrow-operations/cranford-agreement).
> - A historical restriction means    that aircraft cannot take off towards the east from the northern    runway. This is because of the [Cranford Agreement](http://www.heathrow.com/noise/heathrow-operations/cranford-agreement).
> - The hour between    06:00 and 07:00 is the busiest time of the day for arrivals so we are   able to use both runways for landings.
> - Occasionally we have to suspend    runway alternation for airfield maintenance, in response to bad    weather or when air-traffic control
>     want to avoid a build-up of    arriving aircraft.

Actually, alternation also occurs for night flights, but then in 4 one-week periods.

Comment: Take-offs from Heathrow are permitted with up to a 5 knot tailwind component (from memory) so runway changes due to wind direction changes are minimised.